# Json Deserialization failed failed in .NET 5 (Newtonsoft) when using derived class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, json.net

While trying to deserialize a complex derived object Json, which is actually created by serializing a viewmodel object in .NET 5 MVC. I am getting the base class properties of the derived object becomes nullified. Also most of the list items in the Viewmodel like SelectList, Ienumnerable<> also become nullified. I tried with a simple inheritance scenario also with 2 properties, unfortunately then also it failed.

Can someone explain how to solve this.

Example

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode = "99999"; // initialize properties to generate sample data

    public Address()
    { 
        
    }
}

// This will be serialized into a JSON Contact object
public class Contact : Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Contact()
    { 
        
    }
}
public class ContactMain
{
    public Contact contact { get; set; }

    public ContactMain()
    {
        // initialize array of objects in default constructor to generate sample data
        this.contact = new Contact { 
          Id = 7113,
          Name = "James Norris", 
          BirthDate = new DateTime(1977, 5, 13), 
          Phone = "488-555-1212", 
          Address = new Address 
          {
            Street = "4627 Sunset Ave", 
            City = "San Diego",
            State = "CA", 
            PostalCode = "92115" 
          } 
        };

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);

}
```

Then trying to deserialze it with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(jsonString);
```

Makes all the properties in Address Base class null

Comment: how does your JsonString look like?

Comment: Where is the derived class here? I can only see two classes which both inherit directly from object. Please provide a [mcve] - it's hard to help with only part of the picture.

Comment: Note that your PostalCode field should probably be a property, too...

Comment: Please check the class now, I have added the requested data

Comment: @BinilMK I tested and all base props are null but PostalCode is still 99999 like you initialized and that's what's supposed to happen. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I have initialized other properties in the ContactMain class and they are becoming null when deserializing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use base class property to derived class then you can directly call them by derived class object. Address property from Contact class.

```
 public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode = "99999"; // initialize properties to generate sample data

    public Address()
    {

    }
}

// This will be serialized into a JSON Contact object
public class Contact : Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public Contact()
    {

    }
}
public class ContactMain
{
    public Contact contact { get; set; }

    public ContactMain()
    {
        // initialize array of objects in default constructor to generate sample data
        this.contact = new Contact
        {
            Id = 7113,
            Name = "James Norris",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1977, 5, 13),
            Phone = "488-555-1212",
            Street = "4627 Sunset Ave",
            City = "San Diego",
            State = "CA",
            PostalCode = "92115"
        };

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);

    }
}
```

Comment: While this does seem to answer the question OP was looking for, it should be noted that this is inheritance abuse and the classes should not be structured like this to begin with. I'd suggest removing the inheritance and keeping the composition, instead of the other way around.